# does firefly supports Enums

Tags: firefly-mv

Does anyone know if the `firefly.box` infrastructure supports a column that is based on `Enum` that I added to my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: `Firefly.Box.Data.EnumColumn<EnumType>`

Also have a look at: `Firefly.Box.Data.Advanced.CustomColumn<T>`